# Сравнение файлов

Tags: python, строки, файлы, сравнение

У меня есть 2 файла, один из них скачивается из сети и может отличаться от предыдущего. Мне нужно найти их различия, я попробовал, так:

```
a = newResource.readlines()
b = oldResource.readlines()
for lines in a:
    for lines2 in b:
        if lines == lines2:
            print lines + ' == ' + lines2;            
            break;
        else:
            print lines + '!= ' + lines2;
```

Но у меня не вышло, потому, что каждый раз проверяется на одну строку больше из-за содержимого файла. Оно примерно такое.

---

**Старый файл**

- Строка1
- Строка2
- Строка3

---

**Новый файл**

- Строка1
- Строка2
- ЗаменилиСтроку3
- ЕщеОднаСтрока4

---

**И результат примерно такой:**

- Строка1 == Строка1
- Строка2 != Строка1
- Строка2 == Строка2
- Строка3 != Строка1
- и т.д.

---

Как можно сделать без проверки уже проверенных элементров которые удовлетворили условие? Так как, все строки в файлах будут отличаться друг от друга и не повторятся никогда.Может быть кто-то знает как найти различия? Или может есть какие то методы для удаления подстроки из строки? Или какие нибудь другие способы решения проблемы.

Comment: связанный вопрос [сравнение файлов: Как не выводить в результат одинаковые данные в обоих файлах](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/q/571563/23044)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
from itertools import izip_longest

# Превратим файлы в список строк, убрав символы \n в конце строки
l1 = map(lambda x: x.strip(), list(open('test1.txt')))
l2 = map(lambda x: x.strip(), list(open('test2.txt')))

# превратим два списка в один, где каждый елемент первого соответсвует елементу второго.
# Если в одном из спсиков нет соответсвующей строки - будет None
diff_list = izip_longest(l1, l2)

for diff in diff_list:
    print '%s %s %s' % (
        diff[0] or '', 
        '==' if diff[0] == diff[1] else '!=',
        diff[1] or '',
    )
```

результат будет такой:

```
Строка1 == Строка1
Строка2 == Строка2
Строка3 != ЗаменилиСтроку3
 != ЕщеОднаСтрока4Строка1
```

еще в python есть модуль [difflib](http://docs.python.org/2/library/difflib.html) для работы с различиями.
Например он может вывести вашу разницу в таком виде:

```
  Строка1
  Строка2
- Строка3
+ ЗаменилиСтроку3
+ ЕщеОднаСтрока4Строка1
```

с помощью такого кода:

```
from difflib import ndiff

t1 = open('test1.txt').read().splitlines(1)
t2 = open('test2.txt').read().splitlines(1)

print ''.join(ndiff(t1, t2))
```

Comment: +1 за difflib стандартный модуль