# сравнение файлов: Как не выводить в результат одинаковые данные в обоих файлах

Tags: python, diff

Сравниваю два файла

```
from difflib import ndiff
f1 = open('file1.txt').read().splitlines(True)
f2 = open('file2.txt').read().splitlines(True)
diff = ndiff(f1 , f2)
print(''.join(diff))
```

В результат мне выводятся все строчки — одинаковые и различающиеся.
Как мне вывести в результат только различающиеся/отсутствующие/новые строчки строчки? Т.е. не выводить в результат одинаковые данные в обоих файлах.

Comment: в сторону: используйте именованные параметры для булевых параметров: `.splitlines(keepends=True)` более читаемо по сравнению с `.splitlines(True)`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Если результат полностью устраивает за исключением наличия строк, общих для двух файлов, то достаточно отфильтровать строки, начинающиеся на два пробела:

```
print(''.join([line for line in diff if not line.startswith('  ')]))
```

Cм. [Differ-формат](https://docs.python.org/3/library/difflib.html#difflib.Differ).